# How to position the image at the side edges of the screen?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, image

I want to place the image at the edges of the page so that it perfectly touches the left and right sides with the edges.

that's what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATcUJ.jpg

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}



.center {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<img src="images/5-54070_new-york-ultra-wide.jpg" alt="Paris" class="center">
```

Comment: you mean left to right or all edges of screen?

Comment: No one photo will exactly fit all viewport aspect ratios. You can use object-fit cover and give the img full width and height and the system will crop it at the sides or top and bottom as needed. Also remove any margins and padding on ancestor elements.

Comment: Yes I mean left to right. @TheDuo